# Looping over pages until it can't find the next link

Tags: python, loops

I have a function 'find_products()' that loops over the products on a page and prints the model number.  That works fine.  After it scrapes the products from a page I want it to click the next button if present. To test my XPath I am using 'try' to make sure the element is present.  That works but of course, it doesn't loop.  I am struggling to convert this to a loop and keeps calling clicking on 'next page' and calling the product function until the XPath doesn't return a next page link

```
try:
 nextpage=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="srSprite pagnNextArrow"]')
except:
  find_products() # calls function with loop to extract products
  print("Didnt Find Next Page")
  time.sleep(10)
  driver.close()
else:
  find_products()
  nextpage.click() 
  print("i just clicked next page")
  time.sleep(10)
```

Like the approved answer from another user this block of code directly below seems to work.  What I could use some help is what makes the 'try' false in my code sample below?  Is the 'try' failing and becoming false when the find_element_by_xpath returns nothing?  Is this any better or worse then the accepted answer?

```
while True:
 try:    
   nextpage=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="srSprite pagnNextArrow"]')
   find_products()
   print("clicking next page")
   nextpage.click() 
   time.sleep(5)    
 except:
    break

find_products()   #pick up the products on the last page.
```

Comment: Did you try putting it in a `while` loop?

Comment: I figured that is what I needed but was confused about while loops and how it interacts with find_element_by_xpatch.  I have another block of code that is below and I wasnt sure when the True is met.  Is it when the first line of the try(the regex can be found) or is it true until there is an error

`while True:
    try:   
        ViewMore=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@id="list-view__load-more--js"]')
        ViewMore.click()
        print ("Click More")
        time.sleep(2)
      except: 
        break`

Comment: I think that the second block of code is another question and therefore you should raise a new one for that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop and a `bool` variable to check when your scraper had found the next element. You can amend your code like this

```
found = True
while(found):
    try:
        nextpage=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="srSprite pagnNextArrow"]')
    except:
        find_products() # calls function with loop to extract products
        print("Didnt Find Next Page")
        time.sleep(10)
        driver.close()
        found = False
    else:
        find_products()
        nextpage.click() 
        print("i just clicked next page")
        time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: This works.. I also have another solution below that seems to work but I dont understand what makes the 'try' fail.

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to terminate only and only when your code does not find the next page, you should restructure your code as follows:

```
def nextPage():
    is_next_page_found = True

    while is_next_page_found:
        try:
            nextpage=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="srSprite pagnNextArrow"]')
        except:
            # this will terminate the while loop
            is_next_page_found = False
        else:
            find_products()
            nextpage.click()
            time.sleep(10)

  # after breaking out of the loop
  driver.close()
```